# A function which takes an array of tuples as argument, where first element of a each tuple is a parent type of a second

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function in TypeScript that takes an array of Tuples as an argument, where for each tuple the first element must be a parent type of a second element, or, in other words, a second element must extend the first element.

for example:

```
function foo(x: any) {}

abstract class A {
  abstract foo(): any
}
class B extends A {
  foo() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
  }
}
abstract class C {
  abstract baz(): any
}
class D extends C {
  baz() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
  }
}

foo([
 [A, B],
 [C, D]
])
```

Keep in mind that I want to be able to pass classes themselves as values, not their instances (a.k not `new A()`, but rather `A`)

I've tried

```
function foo<A, B extends A>(x: Array<[A, B]>) {}
```

and it works if I pass an array of one tuple, but as soon as I add another tuple it does not work.

I've also tried to create this kind of type

```
type ValidateTuples<T> = T extends Array<[any, any]>
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends [infer A, infer B]
        ? B extends A
          ? T[K]
          : never
        : never
    }
  : never

type CT = ValidateTuples<[[A, B], [C, D]]>
```

That validates if a type is an array of tuples where the first element is a parent of a second type, and if valid returns a type back, otherwise replaces incorrect types with `never`, but I don't know how to actually use it in a function.

My question is, how do I write a function in TypeScript so that it only accepts an array of tuples, where the second element of a tuple must extend the first element?

Comment: What's the actual use-case for this? I'm curious why you'd need this kind of structure (even ignoring TS =)

Comment: I think we need to see a more complete [mre] with use cases to support/reject because this sort of thing can be really fiddly.  The type system compares types structurally so you can have `class X {}` and `class Y {}` and the compiler will accept `foo([[X, Y]])` because `Y` and `X` are structurally identical.  Depending on your exact meaning of "extend" this is either straightforward or impossible.   Take a look at [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqqQqm).  Does it meet your needs?  Or is there some important use case it fails to satisfy?

Comment: @jcalz can you provide that as an answer? I'm friends with the author and it's the solution he was looking for. he'll mark it as an accepted answer as soon he's available. thank you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to make `foo()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` of instance types.  So if you call `foo([[A, B], [C, D]])`, then the generic type argument `T` would be `[A, C]`. And the type of `x` would be a [mapped type over that tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where each element of `T` would be transformed to a pair of class constructor types with the constraint you care about.

Conceptually that looks like this:

```
function foo<T extends object[]>(x: { [I in keyof T]: [
    abstract new (...args: any) => T[I],
    new (...args: any) => T[I]
}) { }
```

For each numeric index `I` of the `T` tuple, the `T[I]` instance type is used twice in the corresponding `I`th element of the type of `x`.  It is the instance type of a (possibly [`abstract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures)) in the first element of the pair, and it is also the instance type of a class constructor in the second element of the pair.

Note that this doesn't quite enforce that the second constructor extends the first one, merely that they both construct and instance of the same type.  But if we make sure `T[I]` is inferred only from the first element of the pair and not the second, this will happen naturally (well, for some definition of "extends").  So we'd like to say that the second `T[I]` is only there for type *checking*, not type *inference*.  There's a longstanding feature request to mark a *non-inferential type parameter usage* at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) with some `NoInfer<T>` operator.  There's no native operator for this, but the GitHub issue describes some ways to implement it that work for some use cases.  Here I'll write one of the suggestions in that issue:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

and now we have

```
function foo<T extends object[]>(x: { [I in keyof T]: [
    abstract new (...args: any) => T[I],
    new (...args: any) => NoInfer<T>[I]
}) { }
```

We're close.  The only issue now is that the compiler might not want to infer `T` as a tuple, since array literals tend to get inferred as unordered arrays and not tuples.  To give the compiler a hint that we prefer a tuple, we can wrap the type of `x` in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (`[...`+`]`):

```
function foo<T extends object[]>(x: [...{ [I in keyof T]: [
    abstract new (...args: any) => T[I],
    new (...args: any) => NoInfer<T>[I]]
}]) { }
```

---

Okay, now let's test it:

```
foo([[A, B], [C, D]]); // okay
// function foo<[A, C]>(x: ⋯): void
```

The correct call is inferred as desired.  An incorrect call should produce an error:

```
foo([[A, D]]) // error
// ----> ~
// Type 'typeof D' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any) => A'.
// function foo<[A]>(x: ⋯): void
```

Here the compiler infers `T` as `[A]`, and since `D` is not a constructor of `A`-compatible objects, there's a warning.  You also get a warning here:

```
foo([[A, B], [D, C]]) // error
// ------------> ~
// Type 'typeof C' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any) => D'.
// Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
// function foo<[A, D]>(x: ⋯): void
```

But only because `foo()` doesn't allow the second element of each pair to be `abstract`.  Your definitions of the `C` and `D` classes didn't distinguish them [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) from each other.  Case in point:

```
class B2 { foo() { } }
foo([[A, B2]]) // this is okay
// function foo<[A]>(x: ⋯): void
```

This is no error because an instance of `B2` is [structurally compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#handbook-content) with `A`, even though there is no `extends` clause in the declaration of `B2`.  TypeScript's type system is largely structural, so it does not recognize or care about any difference between `B` and `B2`.  If you need behavior that does care, you'll have to fight against the type system and/or use various tricks, such as including [`private` or `protected` class members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes).  That's why before I said it depends on your definition of "extends" whether or not this suffices.  Hopefully it *does* suffice, but if not, the discussion of approximating [nominal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) in a structural type system is probably off topic here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXimyggA9gIkATAZygFckBrJOAdySgH5ioAuKEggA3DAG4AUJJRMAxsACWcLijhwcpClTpQ4AIwBWEBQG0AurgAUZQaYB0jgN5RTCKIq7MIIOCmLmdpJQIVAAhvq0wOhhCkIQ7FBWjvZh6ADmtIJhSCAAlIT42G7mADTBocKJyY5pmdm5BQT48MhoWHgl5pIAvuYFLj3SEVExcXIANmG09ACCUE4VISPRscBQanBWeQ0gvZKT0-QAQlqUNHMLSxvq21ehD1DAABboHPGJAKLob+hWAEQAWQgLzg1CEcHWigAtmAJhBoVRKNR7P88tchkNhpFVuMpjMoABhe6hFZjdb6MIAL22u32hwJABEzjp6MTFg9KTSBtcHi83okqlBvr8AcDQeC2FDYfDEUhkaj0Q9MdJNlZTKZZqUoMcyq5CdrGeZ+uIoAB6M16ZhhPYWjbyJQqG4aTXawmWGyCQD3RDsoCI4IpqKrbhqtTq9aZGW7jQU7RhfpI7QBaFOptMp-AAP0Tluw4GgAHJQJA-ESCx56FLwjNFOkkBF4U84E981AC0KaqkMllwo1ClBGQX7DmiTkq0da1wcuEceSoHIVKMGAo4OgW5Am+EIUgk2S1vPF9Fl8BV+uIMO7bIkAplKp1JhXQOPbYoD7BP7A8GtqHDTHzZb41XEc0yzEc8w3It81LQcKwhdYJzrBtoBPM82w7FI6h7HJ8n7WYhxHK8bydTYH1mZ9vV9D8gwOfETgAJgWZ07kGKAhjVH8dTov87ReRR6D4q0bQIh1b2dUjyNfSiAyDIA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, TypeScript Wizard! This solves my issue, and thanks for the explanation as well!